Clarification on quantlib's SwaptionHelper arguments
I am using the following version of Quantlib's SwaptionHelper() to calibrate Hull-White 1F model using market implied volatilities:
SwaptionHelper (
   const Period &maturity, const Period &length,
   const Handle< Quote > &volatility,
   const ext::shared_ptr< IborIndex > &index,
   const Period &fixedLegTenor,
   const DayCounter &fixedLegDayCounter,
   const DayCounter &floatingLegDayCounter,
   const Handle< YieldTermStructure > &termStructure,
   BlackCalibrationHelper::CalibrationErrorType errorType=BlackCalibrationHelper::RelativePriceError,
   const Real strike=Null< Real >(), const Real nominal=1.0,
   const VolatilityType type=ShiftedLognormal, const Real shift=0.0)


I referred to Quantlib Documentation and Quantlib Python Cookbook by Luigi Ballabio and Goutham Balaraman but could not find the definition of &maturity and &length which are the first two arguments of the SwaptionHelper().
The Black Volatility Cube in Bloomberg is given in terms of expiry (in months and years) and tenor (in years) where the former relates to the expiry of the swaption and latter relates to the duration of the underlying swap.
My Question: does the first argument &maturity in SwaptionHelper() will take the expiry as input and second argument &length take the tenor as input to the SwaptionHelper() function?

That's correct.
